# Multi-level Sankey

Tags: apache-superset, sankey-diagram

I am currently using v0.99 of Superset and am able to create a 2 level Sankey diagram.

I would like to plot a sequence of User actions as follows:

Sign up selected -> Base package selected -> Extras selected ->Accounts created ->Sign up completed -> Content Watched.

(a combination of 2-3columns in the Apache druid dataset captures each of the above states)

I was thinking a multi-level Sankey diagram would be useful to capture this flow. Which release of Superset has this support (I don't see it in v0.99)? Is there another way to represent this flow?

Comment: Have you found the solution ?